# Symfony2, How set a Access Control for each Role?

Tags: symfony, twig, access-control

Suppose a scenario like below :

```
Class User {}      // User has Admin Role 
Class Role {}     // Role Admin has Access to choose_date
Class Feature {} // Feature route is choose_date
```

Each User can have One Role. Each role has access to many Features. I have designed the part that Save and Retrieve the Access Matrix for each role. So I know which Role should access to which features and it is saved in a table called roles_features.

Do I have to write my own function to check if the rout is allowed for that Role or not manually. Note: I don't want to use `secuirty.yml` file at all;

```
// In my Twig File
{% if my_own_get_access_matrix(app.user.roles, 'choose_date') %}

    <a href="{{ path('choose_date') }}">
        Edit 
    </a>

{% endif %}
```

I would like to know if there exists any predefined `my_own_get_access_matrix` which return an optimized way of Access Control for each Role and Links or I have to implement mine;

As I wrote, I don't want to use the `secuirity.yml` since Access Control need to be dynamic. So a super user (ADMIN) should be able to define Roles and their Access to Each Feature which is a Route here;

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for [ACLs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html).